# using formGroup when template reference variable is used throws an error

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-forms

I have an existing form with a template reference variable. Now when I want to add formGroup directive the valid property of the template reference variable throws an error.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createTask()"
      [formGroup]="formGroup"
      id="taskFormId"
      autocomplete="off"
      #taskForm="ngForm">
// my code
</form>

<button type="submit"
          form="taskFormId"
          mat-raised-button
          color="primary"
          [disabled]="!taskForm.form.valid">
    Submit
  </button>
```

`[disabled]="!taskForm.form.valid"` throws an error "Cannot read property 'valid' of null". This error shows only when I use `[formGroup]="formGroup"`

Comment: what is your `formGroup` in ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createTask()"
      [formGroup]="yourFormGroup"
      id="taskFormId"
      autocomplete="off"
      #taskForm="ngForm">
// my code
</form>

<button type="submit"
          form="taskFormId"
          mat-raised-button
          color="primary"
          [disabled]="!yourFormGroup.get('yourControlName').valid">
    Submit
  </button>
```